# Is it possible to use id_token to request access token without authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Can OIDC id_token be used as authentication cookie when requesting an access token? i.e. by presenting a valid id_token, client will not gets redirected to user login form.

Comment: It is relentless to downvote this question posted by a newcomer to Stack Overflow. What on earth is the reason for downvoting this question? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your authorization server accepts an ID token as an evidence of authentication, it is possible. It simply depends on the implementation of your authorization server.